# Magento 2.3 - After adding product to cart - But Cart Page, Mini Cart and Chekout showing Empty

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.2.2

I'm facing this issue on my live server, when I'm adding product to cart the ajax requests from (1) to (0). I'm getting this message (Product added successfully) But mini cart, cart page, and checkout are empty. I'm using Magento 2.3.0

anyone can help me regarding this issue?

[image: to]

Thanks

Comment: is your frontend customer account login works? you stay logged all the time?

Comment: Yes, That's working fine. i'm adding products to wishlist's ...and stay login working fine.